# page still loads if user cancels confirmation

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table row which contains a button:

```
<form id='studentAddForm'>
<table id='removetbl'>
<tr>
<td><button id='submitstudents'>Submit Students</button></td>
</table>
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, it displays a confirmation box, hoow come though when I click on the `Cancel` button with in the confirmation box does it still want to load the page? I am getting no errors in my page

Below is jquery code showing click event, confirmation and submit form:

```
function submitform() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updatestudentsession.php",
        data: { 
            sessionid:  $('#currentid').val(),
            students:   $('#addtextarea').val()
        },
        dataType:'json',  //get response as json
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.errorflag) {
                //do your stuff on getting error message
                var newHtml="<span style='color: red'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
                $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);  //i am displaying the error msg here
            } else {
                //you got success message
                var newHtml="<span style='color: green'>"+result.msg+"</span>"; 
                $("#targetdiv").html(newHtml);
                $('#targetdiv').show();
            }
        }
    });        
}

function showConfirm() {
    var examInput = document.getElementById('newAssessment').value;
    if (editvalidation()) {
        var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to add your selected Students to this Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput);
         if (confirmMsg==true) {
             submitform();
         }
     }
 } 

 $('body').on('click', '#submitstudents', showConfirm);
```

**UPDATE:**

I don't know if the information below will help you even further but below shows all of the forms in the page:

**FORM 1:**

```
$assessmentform = "<div id='lt-container'>
<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' id='assessmentForm'>
<p id='warnings'>{$pHTML}</p>
{$outputmodule}
<p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>   
</form>";

echo $assessmentform;
```

**FORM 2:**

```
$editsession = "
<form id='updateForm'>

    <p><strong>Assessment Chosen:</strong></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type='hidden' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<th>Assessment:</th>
<td><input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
</tr>
    </table>
    <div id='currentAlert'></div>
";

echo $editsession;
```

**FORM 3:**

```
    $studentexist="
    <form id='studentExistForm'>
    <p><strong>Current Students in Chosen Assessment:</strong></p>
    <p>{$studentSELECT}</p>
    </form> 
    </div>";

echo $studentexist;
```

**FORM 4:**

```
    $studentremain="<div id='rt-container'>
    <form id='studentRemainForm'>
    <p>{$remainSELECT}</p>
    <table id='addtbl'>
    <tr>
    <td><button type='button' id='addbtn'>Add</button></td>
    <td><button type='button' id='addall'>Select All</button></td>
    <td><button type='button' id='adddeselect'>Deselect All</button></td>
    </table>
    </form>";

echo $studentremain;
```

**FORM 5:**

```
$studentadd="
<form id='studentAddForm'>
<p>{$addSELECT}</p>
<table id='removetbl'>
<tr>
<td><button id='submitstudents'>Submit Students</button></td>
</table>
</form>
</div>";

echo $studentadd;
```

Comment: where is the 'confirm' function defined? it seems that there is where your problem lies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
if (confirmMsg){
     submitform();   
 }else{
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Jai's answer, since you are posting the form through ajax you need to return false from your click handler to prevent the form from submitting, this is what is causing the page to reload;

```
function showConfirm(){

    var examInput = document.getElementById('newAssessment').value;

    if (editvalidation()) {

        var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to add your selected Students to this Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput);

         if (confirmMsg==true)
         {
             submitform();   
         }
    }
    // prevent form submission, defer to ajax post
    return false:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm() {
  //Code to execute before page close
  return 'Any unsaved work will be lost.';
}
window.onbeforeunload=confirm;
</script>
```

This perhaps the simplest way I've found to confirm when you leave a page (such as by submitting a form).

Comment: Why would jquery be needed for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this line is what's giving you grief:

```
var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to add your selected Students to this Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput);
```

The `confirm` function is always returning true, examining this function will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Always return false unless the user confirms, so just add an onsubmit to your forms.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"></form>
```